How should Discussions' replies with "gibberish" be flagged?
The most recent discussion posted in Discussions now was not written in English. So far, it got three replies, all having only "gibberish". OK, strictly, they are not gibberish according to the Wikipedia article; they are nonsensical sequences of characters.
Case 1

SLKMDSL
DMSSSSSSSDJSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Case 2

kkkkkk efg sf d sd f d s df ggdfgsd tf sdf d gdf cxcgze fdcx

Case 3

hagjagasyireowayatdiaoueytrewheb wuaiowdifhgf twyufiogfdishg gduisoiauhg fgsahjk gshjak

The flag options are

Spam
Rude or abusive
Something else.

What option should be used?
I don't think this is a duplicate of How should I handle gibberish answers? because this question is about replies to discussions on "Discussions," not answers to questions, and the rules and revision queues are different.
Related

Can we please red flag discussions?
Can red flags on discussions nuke posts?


R/A is my usual go to for this type of content and they usually get approved. They're not spam as there's no unsolicited advertising, but they are abusive to the format of the site.

Usually, intentional posting of gibberish intended to harm the site is flagged as rude or abusive, as it is abusing the system. That is what I flagged it as. Translating the title yields "THE POWER OF AGRICULTURE IN THE TENTH CENTURY BCE", which is blatantly off topic for Stack Overflow, so a "not suitable for discussions" flag would probably work as well. However, given how off topic it is, it's probably just someone trolling the site (which constitutes for a r/a flag)

does it really matter? the discussion is going to be deleted and with it the replies. It's just discussions, none of that content is useful or matters anyway.

@KevinB Knowing what is the right choice is always matters.

It's rearranging deck chairs on the titanic

@KevinB Yes, it matters, as the flags, if approved, may lead to an account ban / suspension.

Really expect account suspension for posting a gibberish reply?

How about the case of filling with gibberish to bypass word limit when asking question? Should that also be flagged with rude/abusive too?

@ray Your comment is a follow-up question. I think that it was asked/answered before. If you can't find it, please post a new question. P.D. Most questions that use gibberish to bypass the quality filter are VLQ or blatantly off-topic.

@ray No, R/A shouldn't be used on such posts, assuming there's actual content in the question. It should be fairly clear from both the dup-target and Shog9's answer to: "Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?" that using R/A flags on gibberish is restricted to when there's no actual content (and to when it doesn't look like it might be an honest mistake by an established user). Questions of the type you mentioned should be edited. It there's a pattern of the user doing that, then an "in need of moderator intervention" would be reasonable.

@Makyen Is it really appropriate to dupe close this post about Discussions against one about Q&A posts? The flag reasons (and rules altogether) are different between the spaces, and I don't think it's at all clear that the duplicate answers this question about Discussions specifically.

@zcoop98 Yes, it is appropriate. No, the rules for this are not different between the two spaces. There are rules which are different, but not this, nor spam. IMO, the duplicate-target answers this quite adequately. Why would it be different than the policy that's existed for the last 8 to 10 years, just because it's named "Discussions" when the flags are identical? What about calling it "Discussions" makes the garbage posts that we're talking about special or makes it that they should be handled differently than we've been handling them for 10 years?

@Makyen "Why would it be different than the policy that's existed ... just because it's named "Discussions" when the flags are identical?"; I think that your statement here answers the question in exactly the way that the duplicate does not. Giving official guidance that precisely says "R/A content moderation is universal, and should be treated the same way in Discussions as in Q&A", is a valuable answer which is not really given by the duplicate IMO (but is by the answer below, I'll add).

@zcoop98 That it's closed as a duplicate says exactly that it's treated the same. If it had its own question which wasn't closed as a duplicate, that would say that it's different.

Gibberish should be flagged as rude & abusive wherever it occurs on the network.
Shog9 wrote this when he was a Stack Exchange employee.

...I'm partial to "rude or abusive", because enough of them immediately delete and lock the post...

Per this answer by Berthold multiple rude or abusive flags on a discussions post will automatically delete it.

Red flags (spam and rude/abusive) trigger auto-deletion when a post has four of them (or one from a moderator).


Based on the link on the close as duplicate post notice, the canonical answer can be found on Is a post like 'assdddsssafffwq' spam?. (TL;DR: It depends. Use R/A for posts from new accounts and NAA for (accidental?) gibberish post from established users.
